# Code placed BEFORE an Ajax call is executed AFTER the call

Tags: javascript, ajax, spinner

I have an input to enter a username. While typing, I check if the username is available in the code behind.
While checking, the idea is to have a spinner.

Here is my code:

```js
function loginexistscheck() {
  console.log("checking");
  $('#chkunspin').show();
  //document.getElementById("chkunspin").style.display = "block";
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value
  if (!username == "") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Register.aspx/loginexistscheck",
      data: '{newUserName: "' + username + '" }',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        var mesg = document.getElementById("loginavailability");
        switch (response.d) {
          case "false":
            mesg.style.color = "green";
            mesg.innerHTML = "Disponible";
            break;
          case "true":
            mesg.style.color = "red";
            mesg.innerHTML = "Non disponible";
            break;
          case "error":
            mesg.style.color = "red";
            mesg.innerHTML = "Error";
            break;
        }
        //document.getElementById("chkunspin").style.display = "none";
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
      }
    }).done(function() {
      // hide spinner
      $('#chkunspin').hide();
    });
  } else {
    var mesg = document.getElementById("loginavailability");
    mesg.style.color = "red";
    mesg.innerHTML = "Le nom d'utilisateur est requis.";
  };
}
```

```css
.nobr {
  white-space: nowrap
}

#chkunspin {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nobr">
  <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" onchange="loginexistscheck()" required />
  <img src="../images/ajax-loader-un.gif" id="chkunspin" />
</div>
<span id="loginavailability"></span>
```

Here is my problem:
The spinner does start AFTER the Ajax call completes.
I confirmed it with the console.log call.

Any idea what is going on here?

EDIT:

Cleaned up code

```
function loginexistscheck() {
    $('#chkunspin').show();
    console.log("checking");
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if (!username == "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Register.aspx/loginexistscheck",
            data: '{newUserName: "' + username + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                var mesg = $("#loginavailability");
                switch (response.d) {
                    case "false":
                        mesg.css("color", "green");
                        mesg.html("Disponible");
                        break;
                    case "true":
                        mesg.css("color", "red");
                        mesg.html("Non disponible");
                        break;
                    case "error":
                        mesg.css("color", "red");
                        mesg.html("Error");
                        break;
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // hide spinner
            $('#chkunspin').hide();
        });
    } else {
        var mesg = $("#loginavailability");
        mesg.css("color", "red");
        mesg.html("Le nom d'utilisateur est requis.");
    };
}
```

For testing purpose, I added a console.log on the success call.

As a result, I do have the checking before the true on the console but they are both logged at the same time. The Ajax call takes about 30 seconds or so.

The issue remains: why is the spinner not being displayed (nor the checking log) before Ajax is being called?

Comment: Note, `failure` is not a defined `jQuery.ajax()` option

Comment: Your code clearly makes the spinner visible *before* the Ajax request is issued. But, for example it won't hide the spinner when the `username` is empty. (Also you have a strangely inconsistent mix of jQuery and traditional DOM manipulation. If you have jQuery, use it. There is no need to do `document.getElementById('foo')` when you can do `$('#foo')`. The same goes for changing CSS properties or setting element text.)

Comment: I find the mix of jQuery and regular DOM off-putting and confusing.

Comment: I agree with the comments about the mix between DOM and JQuery.
With that said though, it should have no impact on the original issue...
Also, the call is not called when the username is empty...
Should I try beforeSend:on the call?

Comment: General tip, because it's my best guess why your code looks that way. Do not copy and paste code you found somewhere and then bang on it until it somewhat works. Any code you find somewhere (even the code samples from the documentation) needs to be rewritten from scratch. If understand what it does, it should be easy to rewrite it on your own. If you do not understand what it does, you *must* pick it apart until you do. There is no excuse for mashing together code you did not write and then wondering why it's not quite doing what you wanted it to.

Comment: SO, are you claiming that " console.log(response.d);" runs before "console.log("checking");" ? Your explanation is very unclear.

Comment: sorry to have waisted your time. JavaScript is working just fine, and so is the ajax call.
I was not triggering the function at all because I left the focus on the field.

There is truly no issue. sorry again

Answer (score -1):

The input field kept the focus thus never triggering the function.

There is no issue with the code